# how to build a web browser with webkit browser engine for windows

Tags: c#, .net, windows, webkit

Is it possible to build a browser for windows 7 with webkit browser engine? Chrome and safari uses webkit on different platforms. but i just want to build an application that has webkit browser in it.

Note: For development i use Visual Studio 2010. Preferred language is C#.

Comment: Look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084324/net-wrapper-for-webkit

Answer (score 5):

Have you looked at [Webkit.Net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/webkitdotnet/)

I haven't used it but it looks like it might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

checkout http://awesomium.com/ - it is based on Chrome/WebKit and works like a charm.

There is a free license available but also a commercial one and if need be you can buy the source code :-)